# How can I prove that for a Killing vector $\nabla^a \nabla_a \xi^\mu = -R^b_a \xi^a$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, curvature, tensor-calculus, vector-fields

I'm taking a course on General Relativity and I'm trying to prove that for a Killing vector field $\xi^\mu$ the following equation holds:

$$\nabla^a \nabla_a \xi^\mu = -R^\mu_a \xi^a$$

Where $R_ab$ is the Ricci tensor. To prove this I thought of applying the operator $\nabla^a$ to the equation that $\xi$ satisfies due to being a Killing vector field. Then I get:

$$\nabla^a \nabla_a \xi_b = -\nabla^a \nabla_b \xi_a$$

And then I wanted to prove somehow that the RHS is very closely related to the expression that I want to obtain. A little problem is that in the LHS appears $\xi_a$ instead of $\xi^a$ so I would have to raise the index using the metric tensor.

However, I haven't been able to prove this result because I end up with a lot of terms involving different covariant derivatives. I've also tried using Ricci's identity and even the definition of the Riemann tensor but to no avail thus far.

How should I proceed to prove this result?

P.S. I wasn't sure if I should post this question here or in Math SE if it doesn't fit here please flag it to move it to Math SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us look at $-g^{ac} \nabla_a \nabla_b \xi_c$. Because the part symmetric in $(bc)$ vanishes, we have $$-g^{ac} \nabla_a \nabla_b \xi_c = -\frac{1}{2} g^{ac} (\nabla_a \nabla_b \xi_c - \nabla_a \nabla_c \xi_b).$$
Now by the definition of the Riemann tensor, $\nabla_a\nabla_b \xi_c = \nabla_b\nabla_a \xi_c + R_{abc}{}^\mu \xi_\mu$, so $$-g^{ac} \nabla_a \nabla_b \xi_c = -\frac{1}{2} g^{ac} (\nabla_b \nabla_a \xi_c - \nabla_c \nabla_a \xi_b + R_{abc}{}^\mu\xi_\mu) .$$ In this contraction, the first term vanishes by Killing's equation, the second is $\frac{1}{2}\nabla^a \nabla_a \xi_b$ and the third is $-\frac{1}{2}R_b^\mu \xi_\mu.$ The result follows.